# Manage EAR deployed and exploded on Wildfly on the fly

Tags: java, deployment, jar, wildfly, ear

I would like to manage `EAR` deployed and exploded in the Wildfly application server on the fly, meaning to change its content (mainly `JAR` files as submodules) without need to reinstantiate or redeploy the whole package. (which takes time and during the time other modules are not available)

I was trying to do this through the Wildlfy CLI using the commands available for deployment, for example the following commands:

```
/deployment:myapp.ear:remove-content
/deployment:myapp.ear:add-content
```

These commands effectively remove or add content inside exploded application on Wildfly, however it seems to be not deployed without redeploying the whole application again.

Is there any way how to achieve it? Is it feasible?

Comment: It is kind of unorthodox that you would hot-swap specific modules out; what you describe does not sound like you have one application but rather multiple mashed into the same EAR. Is it to manage a specific isolated but shared classpath between them or something?

Comment: You need to redeploy for the classes to be reloaded, there is no magic there.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this all you are looking for in the context of testing your application and not for production kinds of instances.
If so, you can use WildFly standalone mode and a deployment scanner, which can be configured to keep scanning directories for any change and deploy it. Thanks!